# Convert array to arguments for shell command

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do something like:

```
list = Dir["*.mp4"]
`zip "test.zip" "#{list}"`
```

But `#{list}` is coming out as an array, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) from the standard library, which is designed to do exactly this—and does proper escaping no matter how weird your filenames are:

```
require 'shellwords'

list = Dir["*.mp4"]

puts [ "zip", "test.zip", *list ].shelljoin
# => zip test.zip foo.mp4 filename\ with\ spaces.mp4 etc.mp4
```

Comment: Very nice! Amazing the standard libraries available. As soon as you feel like you know them all someone points out a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like you're storing the result anywhere so you should use the multi-argument form of [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) and bypass the shell entirely:

```
system('zip', 'test.zip', *list)
```

Since no shell is invoked, you don't have to worry about quoting or parsing or any of that nonsense, just build a list of strings and splat it.

If you do need to capture the output, then use one of the [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) methods. Backticks are almost always the wrong approach, there are too many sharp edges (just browse the CERT reports for Ruby and you'll see how often backticks and the single argument form of `system` cause problems).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join

You are looking for the join method

```
["a","b","c"].join(" ") => "a b c"

["a","b","c"].join("-|-") => "a-|-b-|-c"
```

Comment: looking at his code i would add a line for `["a","b","c"].map{|x| "'x'"}.join(" ")` as it seems he might need the quotations.